# flutter class double extends

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to have double extends in a single class? in my case, i have class `class AddCreditsState extends State<AddCredits>` i just want to extends the `HookWidget` in my `class AddCreditsState extends State<AddCredits>`,

```
class AddCreditsState extends State<AddCredits>{ // how do i insert the `HookWidget` here?
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(10, 15, 39, 1),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
            width: globals.screenWidth,
            height: globals.screenHeight,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25),
            child: Column(
              children: [headercol, body],
            )),
      ),
    );
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Dart, you can `implements` multiple interfaces, but Dart only supports single inheritance. So, you can not `extends` from multiple classes.

You can though use multiple Mixins with `with`.

But in this particular case, what you probably want is a [StatefulHookWidget](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_hooks/latest/flutter_hooks/StatefulHookWidget-class.html), a StatefulWidget that can use hooks inside its build method.

[image]

### Full source code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'StatefulHookWidget Example',
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatefulHookWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  String _state = 'Hello';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _hookedVar = useState('Hello');
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('StatefulHookWidget Example')),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Text('STATE: $_state'),
            const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
            Text('HOOK: ${_hookedVar.value}'),
            const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() => _state = 'Goodbye');
                _hookedVar.value = 'Goodbye';
              },
              child: Text('CLICK ME'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```